# Adding Information to multiple addresses in schema markup

Tags: schema.org, markup, json-ld

How do I add information to a multiple address schema markup with JSON-LD?

Here is my code:

```
<script type='application/ld+json'>
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Apartments",
  "name": "***",
  "url": "***",
  "address":
  [
    {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
                "streetAddress": "***",
             "addressLocality": "***",
                "addressRegion": "***",
             "postalCode": "***",
             "addressCountry": "Canada"
    },
    {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
                "streetAddress": "***",
            "addressLocality": "***",
                "addressRegion": "***",
            "postalCode": "***",
            "addressCountry": "Canada"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

I would like to add information like geo-coordinates and business hours, but when I try and add it for the individual locations it gives me an error "Expecting 'EOF'" I was trying to add it under the addressCountry part of the code, I'm assuming I am placing it incorrectly.

```
{
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
                    "streetAddress": "***",
                "addressLocality": "***",
                    "addressRegion": "***",
                "postalCode": "***",
                "addressCountry": "Canada"
        },
"geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": "***",
    "longitude": "***"
  },
"openingHours": "Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr 08:00-20:00 Sa, Su 10:00-16:00",

 "contactPoint": {
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "contactType": "Sales",
    "telephone": "***"
}


      ]
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all, about the Schema.org terms you use:**

Your example uses the `Apartments` type, but that is not a valid type. You probably mean [`Apartment`](http://schema.org/Apartment). But this type can’t have the [`openingHours`](http://schema.org/openingHours) property nor the [`contactPoint`](http://schema.org/contactPoint) property. And neither can the [`PostalAddress`](http://schema.org/PostalAddress) have these properties, nor [`geo`](http://schema.org/geo).

As it typically doesn’t make sense for an `Apartment` to have more than one address, I’m not sure if you are really using the correct types here.

Anyway, for providing opening hours, you can use [`openingHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/openingHoursSpecification) property (for `Apartment`) and the [`hoursAvailable`](http://schema.org/hoursAvailable) property (for `PostalAddress`).

**Now about your JSON-LD:**

You cannot nest properties like that.

If you want to add properties to the `PostalAddress` nodes, you have to add them inside the `{` `}` of each `PostalAddress`. That means that you have to repeat them in case they are the same for both nodes.

Comment: It is a community village where the names of the "type of apartments" are sorted so "apartment type 1" is 2 buildings and has 2 addresses. If there is no solution then I will just add the opening hours to the main page of schema and forgo it here. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @KevinS: Can’t say I understand this yet. Anyway, if you want to provide the opening hours of the `Apartment`, you can use the [`openingHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/openingHoursSpecification), and if you want to provide the opening hours of the address, you can use the [`hoursAvailable`](http://schema.org/hoursAvailable) property.